# is the oracle plan output below correct?

Tags: oracle

i got a oracle plan output by plsql-tools,like this :
[image]

i'm definitely sure this is what the plsql-toos shows,i think it is a chaos,the row 18 and the row 16 should be the same level(they should be aligned),like this:
[image]

am i right?or anyone else could tell is the oracle plan output right?

Comment: Please add the relevant schema and the SQL query. And please explain how you interpret the execution plan and why you think it's not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the plan you see is correct. It will perform the following steps in this order:

1. Seek a single row from `PK_BBBBBBBB`,
2. Get the full row from the table `BBBBBBBBB`,
3. then use that to scan on `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_INDEX4`
4. pulling the full rows for matches from the table `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`.
5. For each row found, it will then seek on `PK_CCCCCC` and for each index entry found will visit the table `CCCCCCC`.

The two `NESTED LOOPS` operations are for the `PK_CCCCCC` and `CCCCCCC` objects respectively. Oracle sometimes represents index+table access as each a separate nested loops operation, instead of a single nested loops with the index op nested under the table op.

As for `BBBBBBBBB` feeding `AAAAAAAAAAAA` without a join operation, that's because it's getting a single row from the former that it will use to do the index scan on the latter, and it knows it will be unique because of the PK definition and your predicate (not shown). If `BBBBBBBBB` could provide multiple rows then it would have shown it as a separate branch with a `NESTED LOOPS` operation driving the join to `AAAAAAAAAAA`, as you expected. But you can't just correct the plan like you did with spacing - it would require an additional `NESTED LOOPS` operation (a third) to make sense, and it also completely changes the join order (making `AAAAAAAAAAAAA` first instead of `BBBBBBBBBBB`).